# How to highlight the clicked image and show the name of it in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are images. When I click on one of them I want to highlight it and display the name of it in a list.

**HTML**

```
<img class="high" id="x" src="images/Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="Chrysanthemum" width="300" height="200" onclick="mySelect()">
```

**JS**

```
function mySelect() {
    document.getElementById("x").style.border = "3px dotted blue";
}
```

I'm using this code to highlight. But when I click on any image it doesn't highlight. It only highlights the first image.

[image: example image]

When I click on an image it should highlight. And the name of it should show up in the corresponding `<li>`.

When I click on another image it should highlight this one and unhighlight the one **before**. And the name of the corresponding `<li>` should be replaced with the *placeholder*.

Comment: Use **Jquery** for this type of problem It is faster and easy to do.

Comment: I'm learning **JavaScript** now, I have no idea about **Jquery**

Comment: In my opinion it's better not to start with jQuery. It's always better to understand the **basics** (JavaScript) **first** before using a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to do:

1. **Toggle** class name
2. **Swap** `li.innerHTML` with `img.alt`

   ```
   // List.children.lenght and imgs.children.length must always be the same!

   var imgs = document.getElementById("images");
   var list = document.getElementById("list");
   var cN = "active";

   for (var i = 0; i < imgs.children.length; i += 1) {
       (function(i) {
           imgs.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
               this.className === "" ? this.className = cN : this.className = ""; // Toggle class name

               // Swap img.alt with li.innerHTML
               var temp = list.children[i].innerHTML;
               list.children[i].innerHTML = this.alt;
               this.alt = temp;
           });
       })(i);
   }
   ```

**Complete example**:

```js
// List.children.lenght and imgs.children.length must always be the same!

var imgs = document.getElementById("images");
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var cN = "active";

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.children.length; i += 1) {
    (function(i) {
        imgs.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Toggle class name
            this.className === "" ? this.className = cN : this.className = ""; 

            // Swap img.alt with li.innerHTML
            var temp = list.children[i].innerHTML;
            list.children[i].innerHTML = this.alt;
            this.alt = temp;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

```css
.container ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.container ul,
.container #images {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
}

.container #images img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
    border: 3px dotted brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Image1</li>
        <li>Image2</li>
        <li>Image3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="images">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/70?image=10" alt="Title 1">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/70?image=15" alt="Title 2">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/100/70?image=20" alt="Title 3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show how to select **multiple images** too.

Answer (score 0):

By "name of the image" do you men the "alt" text in the image element?

```
var imageName = document.getElementById("x").getAttribute("alt");

document.getElementById("firstName").innerHtml = imageName
```

Comment: Yes name of the image is "alt"
`function mySelect() {
    var imageName = document.getElementById("x").getAttribute("alt");
    document.getElementById("x").style.border = "3px dotted blue";
    document.getElementById("firstName").innerHtml = imageName
}`
its not replacing the name

Comment: Got it, I copied code and didn't see that you have missed ";" its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution in plain JS, no jQuery required. I suppose this is what you asked for or as close to the required solution?

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("high");
var list = document.getElementById("lstNames");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
 images[i].addEventListener("click", onSelection, false);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  
  a.setAttribute("href", "#");
  a.setAttribute("data-index", i);
  a.innerHTML = images[i].getAttribute("alt");  
  a.addEventListener("click", highlightImage, false);
  
  
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(a);
  
  
  list.appendChild(li);
}
  
  
  function highlightImage()
  {
   var index = this.getAttribute("data-index");
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
     images[i].style.border = "";
      
    images[index].style.border = "3px dotted blue";
  }




function onSelection()
{
 for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
   images[i].style.border = "";



 if(this.style.border === "")
  {
   this.style.border = "3px dotted blue";
  }
  else
  {
  this.style.border = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.details {
  width: 15%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

#lstNames {
  display: inline;
}

#lstNames li {
  list-style: none;
}


.images {
  width: 84%;
  float: left;
  
}


.high {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="details">
  <u>Image selection</u>
  <br/>
  <ul id="lstNames">
  
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img class="high" src="http://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2015/09/pink-chrysanthemum.jpg.638x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg" alt="Chrysanthemum"/>
    <img class="high" src="http://www.caoping8.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/popular-landscaping-pleasant-landscaping-companies-hiring-in-las-vegas-landscaping-las-vegas-jobs-jaramillo-landscaping-las-vegas-jeffs-landscaping-las-vegas-landscaping-jobs-las-vegas-nevada-j.jpg" alt="Rock landscape"/>
    <img class="high" src="http://www.essentialnaturaloils.com/image/data/white%20lotus%202.jpg" alt="Flower"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be done with a few operations:

> 1 - Get The Element

To get The Element there is five ways to make that:

- `document.getElementById('idName')`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('class name')[element index]` (0 base index)
- `document.getElementsByTagName('tag name')[element index]` (0 base index)
- `document.querySelectorAll('.class or #id or tag')[element index]` (0 base index)
- `document.querySelector('.class or #id or tag')` ( will return the first element )

For example we will get the element by class name:

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('high')[0];
```

But `[0]` will get the first image and we need to get all images , so we will make a variable equal to 0 and increase it until it reaching the last image( images.length ) using `for` loop, then put this variable instead of 0

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('high');

for ( var i = 0; i < image.length; i++ ) {
  image[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
     // functions to be invoked
  });
}
```

---

> 2 - Reset the border for all images with each click

Make a function to reset the border of all images using a new `for` loop with a fresh variable

```
function resetBorder() {
  for (var v = 0; v < images.length; v++) {
    images[v].style.border = '';
  }
}
```

---

> 3 - Add the border for the clicked element

For this part we will make a function and give it an argument. then instead of using `this.style.border` ( because it will be referred to the function ) we will add the style to the argument

```
function addBorderTo(thisImage) {
  thisImage.style.border = '4px solid #00f';
}
```

then change the argument to `this` when we call the function `addBorderTo(this);`

---

> 4 - Show the details of the clicked element

We will get the element which hold the image details ( `li` or p )
,then get the alt attribute for the clicked image which hold the image name by the above function

```
function showImageDetails(thisImage) {
    var imgDetails = document.querySelectorAll('.imgDetails p')[1];
    imgDetails.textContent = thisImage.getAttribute('alt');
}
```

---

Then the code could be optimized to look like that:

https://jsfiddle.net/89znymLm/4/

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('high');
var imagesLen = images.length;
var imgDetails = document.querySelectorAll('.imgDetails p')[1];

// loop through each image and and addEventListener for each one
for ( var i = 0 ; i < imagesLen; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    resetBorder();
    addBorderTo(this);
    showImageDetails(this);
  });
}

// make a new loop for each click and reset images by it
function resetBorder() {
  for (var v = 0; v < imagesLen; v++) {
    images[v].style.border = '';
  }
}

function addBorderTo(thisImage) {
  thisImage.style.border = '4px solid #00f';
}

function showImageDetails(thisImage) {
  imgDetails.textContent = thisImage.getAttribute('alt');
}
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 700px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden
}

.imgDetails {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px
}

.imgDetails p:first-child {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.imagesHolder { 
  float: left
}

.imagesHolder li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="imgDetails">
    <p>image selection</p>
    <p>image name</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="imagesHolder">
    <li><img class="high" src="http://placehold.it/150x120/3498db" alt="first image"></li>
    <li><img class="high" src="http://placehold.it/150x120/8e44ad" alt="second image"></li>
    <li><img class="high" src="http://placehold.it/150x120/e74c3c" alt="third image"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way how you can solve it:

HTML:

```
<div>
<div><img class='image' title="title 1" src="https://www.mathconsult.ch/static/unipoly/33.256.gif" ></div>
<div><img class='image' title="title 2" src="https://www.mathconsult.ch/static/unipoly/33.256.gif" ></div>
<div><img class='image' title="title 3" src="https://www.mathconsult.ch/static/unipoly/33.256.gif" ></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.image{
width:150px;
height:150px;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
}

.active{
  border:1px solid #ff0000;

}

.title{

}
```

JS

```
$('document').ready(function(){

   $('.image').click(function(){

   $('.title').remove();
   $('.image').removeClass('active'); //removes old active class

   $(this).addClass('active');
   $(this).before("<div class='title'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</div>");


});

});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6o1se3b/)

Comment: What if the OP doesn't want to use jQuery?

Comment: @Jorrex I showed him one way how it can be done. if OP doesn't want use jQuery then it will not use this i can't see the problem...

Comment: The OP said that he is still learning JavaScript. In my opinion it's better not to confuse a *newbie* with a library!

Comment: @Dest I was just wondering, not to offend you in some way :) I do agree jQuery is the easiest way to go, but if he's still learning Javascript, maybe it's better to start with the roots. If he's willing to learn jQuery, you should know the basics from plain Javascript.

Comment: i did not read that update where OP said he learning javascript... so sorry if i wanted help him ... i have no idea whats wrong with you ... i saw him one way if he wants learn javascript where is problem its just example how to do  with jquery

Comment: jQuery was not tagged. The content of the question and a short look into his profile shows that he is still a *newbie*.